# Setting up this UI with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm trying to set up a view with Auto Layout so that it animates nicely when the view changes size...

The scenario is...

I have a `UIView` with a subView called `animView`. `animView` starts outside of the frame of the view.
As the view grows (gets taller), the `animView` moves down at the same rate.
When the `animView` is 10 points from the top of the view (i.e. @"V:|-10-[animView]" ) it stops and "sticks" to that point.

i.e. something like this...

[image]

Comment: What have you _tried_?

Comment: Loads. Which is why I'm asking this question. I've tired using inequalities, priorities, removing some constraints altogether. None of them even remotely worked so there was little point in posting them. I'm not looking for people to try and guess-hack my code until it works. I can do that myself and I have been doing. I was hoping to get an answer from someone who could actually help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works ([Dropbox share for the project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/h4kyuagmep6bgh0/QIVijNX68o)):

The trick is to use an invisible UIView as a spacer object. The view you call animView is set up like this. Because I set this up partially in IB, it still raises a few issues, but you will see it works like you want.

```
@implementation AnimView {

    UIView * _innerBox;
    UIView * _spacer;
}
```

Then call the method `- setUpEverything` from `initWithCoder:` or `initWithFrame:`.

```
- (void) setUpEverything {


    // Because I set this up in IB with AutoLayout off, I think it 
    // still needs this. Won't work without it
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

    // Otherwise you will see the box outside of animView
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;

    _innerBox = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _innerBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _spacer = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _spacer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    _innerBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _spacer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addSubview:_innerBox];
    [self addSubview:_spacer];

    // Give _innerBox and _spacer some dimensions to prevent ambiguity

    NSLayoutConstraint *i02 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_innerBox attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1.0f constant:50.0f];
    NSLayoutConstraint *i03 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_innerBox attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1.0f constant:50.0f];
    NSLayoutConstraint *s02 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1.0f constant:50.0f];

    // Center both views
    NSLayoutConstraint *i05 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_innerBox attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    NSLayoutConstraint *s04 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];

    // Set the top of _innerBox 10.0 points from the top of the superview with a low priority
    NSLayoutConstraint *i01 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_innerBox attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
    i01.priority = 250;

    // Pin the spacer to the bottom of _innerBox;
    NSLayoutConstraint *i04 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_innerBox attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];

    // Pin the spacer's bottom to the bottom of the superview
    NSLayoutConstraint *s01 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];

    // Stretch the spacer out as needed
    NSLayoutConstraint *s03 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1.0f constant:80.0f];


    [self addConstraints:@[i01,i02,i03,i04,i05,s01,s02,s03,s04]];

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try when I get home.

Comment: OK, this is one of the best SO answers I've ever seen. Not only did you create a whole project for this but you even put a debug mode to help me see what was going on! If I could up vote this again I would do! Thanks

Comment: OK, thought I'd show you the end product from your help :) All set auto layout constraints set up in IB too. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9UPJpG6pr4&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: Nice! Looking good. Did you work out how to get rid of those error message, btw?

Comment: Ooh, I'll have a look. I set it all up in IB so in the end in your project it wasn't using MGView so possibly that fixed it. I'll let you know.

Comment: Had a look at the project again. The Storyboard has AutoLayout turned on which was causing the problems as it adds constraints at run time. I turned AutoLayout off in the Storyboard and it was fine.